# Windows server 2012 URI showing undefined in a file path in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, uri, windows-server-2012, software-packaging

I have a software package which has following components.

1. AngularJS client end
2. Windows service on the server end.

There is a functionality I have - When client requests for a report, I generate it on the server side and save it at a path. 
Path where the file is saved is returned to the client.

Issue here is if i am returning **/reportfolder/filename from server** then on the client side it is becoming **/reportfolder/undefined/filename**.

This is just happening in Windows Server 2012 r2 in IE browser.
When I tested the same in Windows 7 IE browser, no such issue happens.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged the code and found that i was using

> window.location.origin 
>   in java script file to generate the complete report path. 
>   **IE 11** does not support **window.location.origin** in Windows Server 2012. Hence it was returning undefined.

Thanks!